# Removed Python. How to repair ubuntu 20.04 OS without disturbing much of apps?

Tags: 20.04, package-management, python

I have a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version(I am new to Ubuntu), recently I wanted to install the latest version of python i.e. python3.10.0 but was not able to so I looked online and followed many methods but not remember which one worked hence, I won't be able to tell what I used.Then the next day when I tried to open the terminal it was not working so I looked up the internet and it said that it might be because of the recent things I installed and as the latest thing I did was to install python and I remembered a warning regarding the installation of python3.10.0 that came up during the installation process but I ignored it so, I thought of removing python from the system I did that using something as  `Clt+Alt+F3` but I messed up the python of the OS. Since then many applications are not opening including terminal, is there a way to fix this without installing Ubuntu20.04 again because I don't want to do the process again and then install the third party packages once more and also my important files will be lost. I want a solution that will repair whole OS without disturbing much of apps and packages(It is okay if some apps and packages are removed but not all)

**Note**: I have synaptic package manager,dconf-editor,gdebi package manager if needed I can use them.

**Edit**: If everything is removed it is okay and I have created backup for files but don't want to install it over again.

Comment: Numerous parts of Ubuntu rely on the version of python that's distributed with your version of Ubuntu.  Installing a different version was a big mistake.  You are new to Ubuntu and this mistake will cause widespread problems. You should reinstall. It won't take as long as it will take you to fix all the little problems. It's a good thing you have backups

Comment: If you removed `python3` from the system in your *attempts to fix things* you'll likely find `gdebi` & other tools you had are no longer there; or are not operational (or may do damage instead of helping you); eg. look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gdebi and you'll see it *depends* on python3 being present & working (*with it being the version the system came with too usually*).  You can re-install a desktop system without starting again (do use any option that performs format!)

Comment: If you need a specific python version for a task, set up an environment or use a VM or other container so that it does not wreck your system

Comment: Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1377304/124466 If it does not work, you will have to reinstall.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810854/i-deleted-package-python3-on-ubuntu-and-i-have-lost-dashboard-terminal-and-un)

Comment: Thank you for trying your best but nothing is working, I guess I will have to install it again

Comment: Your *apt* logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) should tell what you did exactly did; and thus what will reverse it if you look re: package changes,  but until you've re-installed at least python3-minimal (with the correct python3 version & reverse and incorrect version changes) you'll have to limit yourself only to base programs that don't use python (ie. `wget` & `dpkg` etc. will still work); even if easier front-ends aren't currently working as they need python3 fixed first. Again re-install is faster & can auto-reinstall *manually installed* packages from Ubuntu repos & not touch your files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed Python 3 and now Ubuntu Software Center, terminal and other applications don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384033/removed-python-3-and-now-ubuntu-software-center-terminal-and-other-applications)

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally deleted python3 under `/usr/lib` on Ubuntu 20; you could've messed it one way or another as well; my system afterwards won't update, launch the terminal or run software updates. You do **NOT** need to reinstall your Ubuntu.

Here is how I solved the problem:

1. boot your system from a USB Ubuntu stick
2. Do not install, choose to "Try Ubuntu"
3. Launch the terminal on your Ubuntu (which you are running in try mode on the USB stick).
4. Open two tabs in terminal:

   - one that is pointing to your local Ubuntu stick path `/usr/lib`
   - another pointing to "Other locations" where you point to the local drive of your computer's `/usr/lib`. Typically under `/media/some hash code/../usr/lib`
5. from properties, copy the path of your `/usr/lib` of your mounted drive on you PC. It would be something under `/media` path.
6. `cp -r /usr/lib/python3` into your mounted local drive path on your PC where `/usr/lib` is. If you had messed it up, delete the local one, and copy the one from the usb stick.
7. Shutdown your running Ubuntu (try-mode on USB stick) and Start Ubuntu on your PC as usual.
8. You will need to fix some apport dependencies that are installed already on your system, but are not *yet* hooked to your system's python3 environment. To do that:

   1. Open the original terminal that comes with Ubuntu. You can do that now from the applications' launcher, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to go to tty terminal (to go back to Gnome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>).
   2. When you open the terminal, you get an error message before the prompt. Read through, and it is already naming a missing package.
   3. The named missing package(s) are not pip installable, rather apt installed. Install the respective package with the command:

      ```
      apt -f install --reinstall <package name>
      ```
   4. Then close the terminal, and reopen again the terminal. You will need to do that incrementally. So, you will get another name for a missing python package being imported by python but not found. Again, install it the same way with apt as above. Incrementally doing so until all errors are gone, and all hooks are re-established.
   5. Finally, run:

      ```
      sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
      ```

      P.S. note that, if you had `gnome-tweaks` installed, you will need to reinstall it as well:

      ```
      sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-tweaks
      ```

And you are done.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`$ apt -f install` Reboot. If it's still not right, try: `$ dpkg-reconfigure -a` Reboot. It should be working for sure, unless you messed up the package database in `/var` Let us know how it goes. Write down all the errors, in case we need them to further assist you.

I wouldn't worry. I used to get into a mess all the time. It's how you learn!

Comment: I tried both the options but every time a lot of errors come most of them say that some python packages are not properly installed and in the end it comes like this “E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)”

Comment: Try this, `$ touch test.txt` `$ apt -f install > test.txt` `$ dpkg-reconfigure -a >> test.txt` Notice there are (2) '>' in the second one. afterward, paste the file to a pasteboard and put the link to it  in your question. Also, try `$ ls /var/cache/apt/archives > list.txt` and paste that one too. See if there are any python packages in list.txt. Install them with `$ dpkg -i --force-depends <full path and file name - extension>`

Comment: I tried the commands but every time it says permission denied in both `$ touch test.txt` and `ls/var/cache/apt/archives > list.txt` what shall I do next?

Comment: Shall I format my laptop and install ubuntu again because my work is stuck because this issue as the apps that I use for work are not working .. ?

Comment: If time is a factor, and your not fast at Linux yet, it might make sense to reinstall. You need to use `sudo` for `permission denied` errors.

Comment: @mrxking no, don't do that, you should not loose hope

Comment: @Brian What do you even mean? By `apt -f install` ? What will it even do in this case?

Comment: `apt -f install` is designed to rescue a system with package dependency problems. It is so ubiquitous I wrongly assumed my meaning was intuitively obvious. Please accept my apology.